# How to get props from JSX passed as props with Enzyme shallow render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I rendered a component with shallow render like this:

```
render() => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Component
                prop1="value"
                prop2="value"
                prop3={
                    <AnotherComponent prop={[1, 2, 'apple']}/>
                }
            />
        <div>
    )
}
```

I can easily test the "Component" props, but I can not get access the "AnotherComponent" props.
I tried to extract the XML to a variable like this:

```
const anotherComponent = wrapper.find(Component).prop('prop3');
const renderedAnotherComponent = shallow(anotherComponent);
```

but they have undefined props. What would be a solution for this? I would like to stick with shallow render because it runs faster.

Comment: The other prop should be rendered already, not sure you need to do the extra shallow render

Comment: no it is not rendered